# How do websites(especially news) keep their core web vitals as passed (in green) even though their page performances are considerably low

Tags: performance, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, core-web-vitals, web-vitals

Lets see https://www.hindustantimes.com/, their web vitals are passed on pagespeed but their performance is 40 with lcp, tbt in red. How are they managing this?
https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-www-hindustantimes-com/oy24q1p8z6?form_factor=mobile

I researched a bit and found out Core Web Vitals Assessment takes out the average but on what basis this happens

Comment: This seems more like a question for [webmasters.se].

Comment: Your question should be answered here: https://web.dev/articles/lab-and-field-data-differences